# Amazon EC2 public ipv6 address

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipv6, amazon-route53

As Apple starts rejecting applications which are not able to communicate in ipv6 only network, it is required to also have a public ipv6 address for my web service which uses TCP and UDP.

The web service is hosted in Amazon EC2 VPC, I have followed instructions on Amazon docs to enable ipv6 routing in VPC. But I don't have any **public** domain or static-ipv6 to connect to EC2 instance.

After searching I came to know about route53 service which can register a domain and point it to some ipv6 / ipv4.
Is the correct solution? Can a single domain map to both ipv4 & ipv6?
for example, mywebservice.amazon-ec2.com points to same ec2 instance having ipv4 and ipv6.

Will requesting the mywebservice.amazon-ec2.com from ipv6 only network work?

If I misunderstood something please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct.

You can create a **two Record Sets** in Amazon Route 53:

- One `A` record pointing to the IPv4 address
- One `AAAA` record pointing to the IPv6 address

For the IPv4 address, first allocate an [**Elastic IP Address**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-eips.html) to the instance because it is a static address that will not change when the instance is stopped/started. Then, point the `A` record to the Elastic IP Address.

There is no Elastic IP Address available for IPv6. Instead, just point to the instance's normal IPv6 address, which will always stay the same for that instance.

You don't actually need to use Amazon Route 53 -- any DNS service will provide the same functionality.

See Amazon Route 53 documentation: [Values for Basic Resource Record Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-basic.html)

Comment: Registered a free domain with dynu.Its working now, thank you again for support.

Comment: Hi @YashKansagara, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, does every instance have an IPV6 Address? or do you need to create one some how? Some info on how to get an IPv6 Address would be nice.

Comment: @Eric, please start a new Question rather than asking a new question in a comment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein isn't that part of this question "I don't have any public domain or static-ipv6 to connect to EC2 instance." If there is no ipv6 address, then knowing how to add the DNS doesn't help.